# How to retain parenthesis when adding to an empty tuple

Tags: python, nested, tuples

I have this tuple:

```
l = [(0,1), (4,5), (7,10) ]
```

I create an empty tuple and add 1st and 3rd item from l to it:

```
res = ()
res += l[0]
res += l[2]
```

The output for res is:

```
(0,1,7,10)
```

How do I make this into this form: `[(0,1), (7,10)]`?

Answer (score 2):

Your desired output is a list, not a tuple. So make it a list and append the objects you want in there:

```
res = []
res.append(l[0])
res.append(l[2])
```

Or the immediate list literal:

```
res = [l[0], l[2]]
```

Given the size and regularity of your sample data, this could also be done using slice notation:

```
res = l[::2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote you want tuples but show lists in your examples.
Here is a way to add the tuples and result in a tuple of tuples.

```
res = ()
res += (l[0],)
res += (l[2],)
```

res is now:

```
 ((0, 1), (7, 10))
```